# How do I prevent duplicate items on browser reload?

Tags: java

I have a controller and JSP page. When I run the controller on the server for the first time the result was as expected for the second time when I run, duplicate data was displaying. Can anyone help me how to prevent that?
Really need help in this trying for the past few days but didn't get any suitable solution.

This is the controller:

```
package com.luv2code.web.jdbc;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class StudentControllerServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/StudentControllerServlet")
public class StudentControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private StudentDButil studentDbUtil;
    
    @Resource(name="jdbc/web_student_tracker")
    private DataSource dataSource;
    
    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        
        // create our student db util ... and pass in the conn pool / datasource
        try {
            studentDbUtil = new StudentDButil(dataSource);
        }
        catch (Exception exc) {
            throw new ServletException(exc);
        }
    }
    
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            listStudents(request,response); 
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
    }

    private void listStudents(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws Exception {

        // get students from db util
        List<Student> students = studentDbUtil.getStudent();
        
        // add students to the request
        request.setAttribute("STUDENT_LIST", students);
                
        // send to JSP page (view)
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/list-students.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

And the JSP page is:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*,com.luv2code.web.jdbc.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
Student Tracker App
</head>
<% List<Student> theStudent=(List<Student>)request.getAttribute("STUDENT_LIST"); %>

<body>
    <%= theStudent %>
</body>

</html>
```

StudentDbUtils.java

```
package com.luv2code.web.jdbc;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class StudentDButil {

    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    
    private DataSource datasources;
    
    public StudentDButil (DataSource thedatasources)
    {
        datasources = thedatasources;
    }
    
    public List<Student> getStudent() throws Exception
    {
        Connection mycon = null;
        Statement mystmt = null;
        ResultSet myres = null;
        try {
            mycon = datasources.getConnection(); //get DB connection
            String sqlStmt = "select * from student order by last_name"; //write an sql statement
            mystmt = mycon.createStatement(); //create sql statement
            myres = mystmt.executeQuery(sqlStmt); //execute query
            while(myres.next())
            {
                //retrive data from resultset
                int id = myres.getInt("id");
                String fname = myres.getString("first_name");
                String lname = myres.getString("last_name");
                String emailid = myres.getString("email");
    
                Student std = new Student(id, fname, lname, emailid); //create student object
                students.add(std); //add student object to list
            }
            return students;
        }
        finally
        {
            close(mycon, mystmt, myres); //close jdbc connections
        }
        
    }
    
    private void close(Connection mycon, Statement mystmt, ResultSet myres) {
        try {
            if(myres!=null)
            {
                myres.close();
            }
            if(mystmt!=null)
            {
                mystmt.close();
            }
            if(mycon!=null) {
                mycon.close(); //dosen't really close it. just puts back into the connection pool
            }
            
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    //get DB connection

}
```

Comment: Maybe HashSet could help you? Use it instead of a list. You should define hashCode and equals methods to use the set. Lombok can help you to do it easy https://projectlombok.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the problem is in `StudentDbUtils` where you declare the `students` list on the class level. Each time you access/reload the page, `doGet` calls `listStudents` which calls `getStudent` and the method adds the retrieved students from the database to the `students` list. Therefore, you have duplicates starting from the second call of `getStudent`. This is so because the servlet is only instantiated once and therefore the `studentDbUtil` is only created once. You are calling `getStudent` on the same instance of `StudentDbUtil` where the list still contains the entries from the previous call.

To fix this, you need to create an empty list for the students inside the `getStudent` method and remove the attribute in the `StudentDbUtils`. Additionally, you can entirely remove your `close` method by using *try-with-resources* which gives you much cleaner code.

Below is an example of how you could write the `StudentDbUtil` class. I used `PreparedStatement` to show where to add parameters in case you need it later (for example to get a student by id).

```
public class StudentDbUtil {

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    public StudentDbUtil(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public List<Student> getStudent() throws SQLException {
        String sql = "select * from student order by last_name";

        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            // set parameters here if necessary
            // example: "stmt.setInt(1, id);" for "WHERE id=?"
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    int id = rs.getInt("id");
                    String firstName = rs.getString("first_name");
                    String lastName = rs.getString("last_name");
                    String email = rs.getString("email");
                    students.add(new Student(id, firstName, lastName, email));
                }
            }
        }
        return students;
    }
}
```

<sup>PS: Try to avoid the prefixes *my* and *the* for attribute and variable names as they do not add any information. It's always good to be consistent and use meaningful names. That is the reason why I changed some names in my snippet above.</sup>